# React - keep Firestore listening function running in the background across pages and reloads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using ReactJS and I want to keep a Google firestore listening function running while a user navigates my website, reloads the page, uses the back button, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, you should have a primary 'app' component or something, just attach the event listener to that

Comment: when I attach the event listener there, the listener is called after a page reload; I also want to be cost effective with regards to Firestore reads because every time the listener is called, a snapshot of the data is taken which costs x reads; I want to avoid unnecessary snapshots of the data

Comment: I don't think there's a way to avoid re-attaching the listener on page reload. When you refresh the page the app is refreshed so it has to re-attach the event listener.

Comment: Ya I figured, thx for the help though! Moving it to the app fixed the other cases at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you should have a primary 'app' component or something, just attach the event listener to that